# Include developer app in response of access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, apigee

Using client credentials, the client is hitting apigee. but in response how to include developer app name?

```
 curl https://{org}-test.apigee.net/oauth/client_credential/
  accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials -X POST -d 
  'client_id={consumer_key}&client_secret={consumer_secret}'
```

the response is as follows

```
   {  
  "issued_at" : "1382703699776",
   "application_name" : "8586c7b7-2936-4779-b7a6-97014e436d7d",
  "scope" : "READ",
  "status" : "approved",
  "api_product_list" : "[PremiumWeatherAPI]",
  "expires_in" : "3599",
  "developer.email" : "tesla@weathersample.com",
  "organization_id" : "0",
  "client_id" : "SJOaCEGohSu3vpNswMs5YdBlc2GOAh1J",
  "access_token" : "UAj2yiGAcMZGxfN2DhcUbl9v8WsR",
  "organization_name" : "myorg",
  "refresh_token_expires_in" : "0",
  "refresh_count" : "0"
   }
```

in response I need developer app name also which is associated with that secret and key.
How to include that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://{org}-test.apigee.net/oauth/client_credential/accesstoken` is a proxy API call, not a management server API call. You have full control over your token response, including adding and removing fields. In fact, I think it is rare when all of the default returned fields make sense.

Inside the `OAuthV2` policy doing the `GenerateAccessToken` operation, use the following configuration:

```
<GenerateResponse enabled="false"/>
```

After the token has been minted, flow will continue instead of immediately returning. You can then create the response manually using flow variables.

For example, to return just the access token, the expires_in field, and the application name, you could use the following `AssignMessage` in your response flow:

```
<AssignMessage enabled="true" continueOnError="false" async="false" name="AccessTokenResponseCC">
    <AssignTo createNew="true" transport="http" type="response"/> 
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Set>
        <Payload contentType="application/json" variablePrefix="%" variableSuffix="#">
{
    "access_token":"%oauthv2accesstoken.GenerateToken.access_token#",
    "expires_in":"%oauthv2accesstoken.GenerateToken.expires_in#",
    "app_name":"%apigee.developer.app.name#"
}
        </Payload>
    </Set>
</AssignMessage>
```

where "GenerateToken" is the name of the OAuthV2 policy where the access token was created. In my Apigee cloud org, the variable `apigee.developer.app.name` is populated after token creation.

See the [OAuth flow variables page](http://apigee.com/docs/ja/api-services/api/oauth-flow-variables) for more variables you can use.

Comment: Completey forgot it was in the variables... Much better solution

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that is the final response from Apigee and you can't actually manipulate it after the fact (like you would with an outside service).  The only option I see is to mash up Apigee with Apigee, which will get a little ugly:

**1) Mint your token in a callout:**
Rather than attaching the OAuth policy in your flow to mint your token, you create a second flow with a different basepath (something like /otherfunctions/oauth/token).  Your developer calls /v1/oauth/token and you pass their credentials on to /otherfunctions/oauth/token which returns a payload you can now edit either in JavaScript or in an AssignMessage payload

**2) Get your Developer Name from the Apigee API:**
This is tricky because you're going to have to create an Apigee Edge user with a limited role so you don't store your personal credentials in your API proxy, the Username and Password is your log in to the Management server (see the Organization Roles in the UI to create a custom role; set up a custom user by using registering with a valid email address and then add them to your org with the custom role).

```
Authorization: Basic {base64 management api username:password)
https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{org_name}/apps/{application_name}
```

Where {application_name} is that long UUID in the response payload when the token was generated (e.g. 8586c7b7-2936-4779-b7a6-97014e436d7d). Then you can get the app name and mash it up with the original payload.

You'll probably want to cache the heck out of that call to api.enterprise.apigee.com but even so you're going to get a performance hit doing it this way.

Alternatively, you could build a separate API path that returns app details and let the developer do two calls and mash it up on their own...

Comment: Better to use a custom response I think.

Comment: This basically is a custom response, but you still need to mint a token.  I suppose rather than looping back into yourorg-test.apigee.net you could use api.enterprise.apigee.com to generate the initial token rather than the policy.  Docs can be fond here: https://apigee.com/docs/management/apis